# Python for loop multiply lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, for-loop

i have 2 lists and i need to loop trought the lists without sort the lists.

Here are my code:

```py
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [1,2,6,3,8,9]

for i in range(len(a)):
    for y in range(len(b)):
        if a[i] == b[y]:
            print("nr: "+ str(b[y]))
```

So the problem is the number 3 in the second list.
it is printed before the number 6 is printed.

But i need the number 6 first.

can anyone halp me?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you i want to point out that there is no need for you to iterate through the ***length of the list*** when you can just simply iterate through ***the list***
like this:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [1,2,6,3,8,9]

for i in a:
    for y in b:
        if i == y:
            print("nr: "+ str(y))
```

Clean and simple

## LOOP INSIDE A LOOP

You are getting 3 before 6 because of the order of 3 and 6 in the list `a`
Here you have 0 as the first element of list `a` when loop starts so i=0 is assigned, the cursor moves to the second line where you are iterating through another list `b` and i remain equals to 0 until you have not checked for its equality with every item on list `b`.
 After going through the last element of list `b` the cursor comes back to the first line of loop and i=1 is assigned and so on

i=3 is assigned before i=6 can get a chance because
`a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Just change the order of list `a`

set `a = [0,1,2,6,4,5,3,7,8,9,10]`